# Galereya Multiple categories per image

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how to assign multiple categories to a single image in Galereya?

I have this HTML on page with the jQuery script:

```
<body class="royal_preloader">
   <div id="royal_preloader"></div>
   <div class="HeaderArea" id="headerArea">My title area etc</div>
   <div id="gallery"></div>
   <footer>
      Galereya
   </footer>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
   <script src="src/js/jquery.galereya.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(function() {
          $('#gallery').galereya({
              spacing: 16,
              load: function(next) {
                  $.getJSON('images.json', function(data) {
                      next(data);
                  });
              }
          });
      });
   </script>
</body>
```

Then I have this in the JSON File

```
[{"lowsrc":"upload\/thumbnails\/image-1.jpg","fullsrc":"upload\/image-1.jpg","description":"Description text","category":"drawing" }, 

{"lowsrc":"upload\/thumbnails\/image-2.jpg","fullsrc":"upload\/image-2.jpg","description":"Description text","category":"photography"},

{"lowsrc":"upload\/thumbnails\/image-3.jpg","fullsrc":"upload\/image-3.jpg","description":"Description text","category":"drawing”}]
```

What I'd like is:

```
{"lowsrc":"upload\/thumbnails\/image-3.jpg","fullsrc":"upload\/image-3.jpg","description":"Description text","category":"drawing” "painting" "sketch"}
```

So that when a user chooses any of those three categories, the image will display in the chosen category.

1 image, several categories.

Thanks, looking forward to some help.

Comment: Could you paste some code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @heramble. As DavidFang mentioned, please could you provide code which you have attempted to get working as per your needs with your question. This was the users can more easily assist.